# Python - SSL Client/Server Certificate

Tags: python, authentication, ssl, openssl, certificate

I want to create a Client/Server architecture following the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/ssl.html).

This works well with my self-signed certificates in one pem file. (ca_root root_key ca_intermediate intermediate_key)

So my next plan is to create client certificates which can be revoked by the server if the client isn't trustworthy anymore.

So the way to go is that i create a certificate, signed with the intermediate key, and hand it out to the client.

But i still get

`ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)`

Do i need to export the whole certificate chain to the client? This seems odd to me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you're entire chain isn't in your .pem file. Just copy the text from the certificates in the right order into a single .pem file and attempt that. If that doesn't work you may be getting this error because of your server configuration. More information is need thought to provide a better answer.